# Подскажите онлайн трансляторы GCC С++, в которых можно транслировать многофайловые проекты

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Добрый день.

Пользуюсь в основном Visual Studio, но иногда нужно чтобы код транслировался и под GCC.

Есть много онлайн трансляторов, где можно оттранслировать один файл. Например, я пользовался http://cpp.sh (хотя он периодически отключается на 40 минут или еще иногда глючит и выдает результат соседнего проекта). Но там можно транслировать только однофайловые проекты.

Ставить cigwin неохота, и так машина переполнена мусором. Тем более, что часто надо проверить только сам факт трансляции проекта на GCC.

Поэтому вопрос:

1. Подскажите онлайн трансляторы GCC С++, в которых можно транслировать многофайловые проекты.

Спасибо.

Comment: Поставьте себе на машину mingw или clang и используйте их прямо из студии.

Comment: А онлайн таких сервисов нету что-ли? Может самому сделать, если рыночная ниша пустует. :-)

Comment: Ну wandbox.org есть, но с несколькими файлами это же сколько геморроя будет их туда заливать.

Comment: Да это один раз только сделать. Спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: Зачем онлайн сервисы, когда есть оффлайн mingw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобные сервисы конечно же существуют.

- https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler  - можно создавать много файлов и даже отлаживаться
- https://wandbox.org/ -  большой выбор компиляторов и буста.  И конечно, можно создать многофаловый проект.
- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ - любимый некоторыми на этом сайте сервис (потому что правильный:) ). Создавать многофайловый проект можно, но хитро - через расшаривание (описано в документации).

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно посмотреть в сторону https://www.onlinegdb.com/ помимо многофайловых проектов также присутствует возможность отладки и интерактивного ввода/вывода.

Но в чем проблема установить clang или gcc?
Под Windows Вы можете использовать MSYS2 и с его помощью установить всё необходимое.